# Is there a compile time way in TypeScript to declare a keyof type, of only the keys that map to a specific type?

Tags: typescript

Imagine we have the following types:

```js
interface User {
    name: string
}

interface Session {
    id: string
    startTime: number
    moderator?: User
    student: User
    instructor: User
    observer: User
}
```

Is there a way to get a `keyof` from `Session`, that's only for the keys that are of type `User` ? In this case that would be `"moderator" | "student" | "instructor" | "observer"` but not `"id" | "startTime"`. Let's say in **any** version of TypeScript (if this has changed or there's a language feature in the works), but I'm using 4.1.2 for reference.

**Edit for Associated Question**
The linked question does answer this question completely although I feel like this more generic phrasing is useful. I also made one of the `User` fields optional because my real code has optionals and that threw me. A one liner for my specific issue (based off the linked question) is:

`type UserKeys = {[K in keyof Session]-?: Session[K] extends User|undefined ? K : never}[keyof Session];`

*Note the `-?` and `User|undefined` if you have optionals.

Comment: Translating the answer from the other question here yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/DmMo1w).

Comment: The associated question does answer my question although I do think the titles could be improved as the answer is not string specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is using mapped types

```
type UserKeys = {
  [Key in keyof Session]: Session[Key] extends User ? Key : never
}[keyof Session]
```

Comment: This is a correct answer but I think the way I phrased this question should just link to the associated question.

Comment: Sure, I agree! It also shows a general solution